# Create SSH web link

Tags: google-chrome, ssh, ssh-tunnel, links

I want to create an **SSH//:** link to be displayed on internal website. I currently SSH to Machine-B via Machine-A, I fisrt SSH to Machine-A then from there I SSH to MAchine-B as I cannot SSH to Machine-B directly. I am using below command to SSH to Machine-B directly by entering passwords for both machine as prompted on same screen at once.

> ssh user@Machine-A -p  ssh user@Machine-B

I want to create a web link to do the same thing where user will click on **`SSH//:`** link which will open SSH client in browser(I am using chrome with SSH client extension). I am not sure and could not find how to create a link to achieve this.

Comment: You could create private key / authorized_keys authentication - and using something like pageant to save your keys? Unless you must run ssh session on the browser due to computer restriction?

Comment: @Darius: yes, requirement is to run ssh session in browser.